# ¿Cómo puedo separar un pares en un array e impares en otro array con numeros aleatorios?

Tags: array, c, bucle-for, condiciones, while

Debo de hacer un programa que tenga un array o arreglo de 100 números aleatorios entre 1 y 1000. Una vez creado organizarlo de tal manera que almacene los números pares en un array o arreglo y los
impares en otro. ¿alguien me ayuda?

Ya avance un poco pero no estoy seguro que vaya de la manera correcta

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int numeroAleatorio[100];
    int numero1[100];
    int numero2[100];
    int i, j;
    int hayRepeticiones;

    srand (time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<=100; i++) {
        numeroAleatorio[i] = rand()%1000;
          }

           hayRepeticiones = 1;

           //Comprobar repeticiones
            while (hayRepeticiones == 1) {
               hayRepeticiones =0;
              for (i=0; i<=100; i++) {
              for (j=i+1; j<=100; j++) {

                if (numeroAleatorio[i] == numeroAleatorio[j] && numeroAleatorio[i] !=1000) { 
                    printf("Hay repeticion. Cambio de %d por %d \n", numeroAleatorio[i], 
                numeroAleatorio[i]+1);
                    numeroAleatorio[i] = numeroAleatorio[i] +1;
                    hayRepeticiones = 1;

                }
                if (numeroAleatorio[i] == numeroAleatorio[j] && numeroAleatorio[i] ==1000) { 
                    numeroAleatorio[i] = numeroAleatorio[i] -rand()%28+1;
                    printf("Hay repeticion de 29. Cambio de 29 por %d \n", numeroAleatorio[i]);
                    hayRepeticiones = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        }

        for (i=0; i<=100; i++) {
        printf("Aleatorio %d vale: %d\n", i, numeroAleatorio[i]);
        if(numeroAleatorio%2==0{numeroAleatorio=numero1});
        else(numeroAleatorio=numero2);
        printf("numeros pares%i",numero1);
        printf("numeros impares%i",numero2);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Podrías empezar por lograr que compile.

Answer (score 3):

Recorre tus números, si es par lo guardas en un sitio, si es impar lo guardas en otro:

```
for (int i = 0, par = 0, impar = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    switch (numeroAleatorio[i] % 2)
    {
        case 0: // Par.
            numero1[par++] = numeroAleatorio[i];
            break;
        case 1: // Impar.
            numero2[impar++] = numeroAleatorio[i];
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El código propuesto como solución lo que hace es extraer de un array aquellos números pares que puede contener, como también los números impares, quedando los pares almacenados en un array y los impares en otro array y luego ambos se muestran en pantalla.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int numeroAleatorio[100];
    int numero1[100];
    int numero2[100];
    int i, j, f;

    /*cargar numeros aleatoreos*/
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        numeroAleatorio[i] = rand()%1000;
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    f = 0;

    /*recorrer numeros aleatoreos*/
    while(f < 100){
        if(numeroAleatorio[f] % 2 == 0){
            numero1[i] = numeroAleatorio[f]; /*cargar numeros pares*/
            i++; /*iterador de numero1*/
        }else{
            numero2[j] = numeroAleatorio[f]; /*cargar numeros impares*/
            j++; /*iterador de numero2*/
        }
        f++; /*iterador de numeroAleatorio*/
    }

    /*cuando ciclo while termina los iteradores 'i' y 'j' salen con la cantidad de numeros que se cargaron en numero1 y numero2 respectivamente
    gracias a ellos podemos recorrer los dos array*/

    printf("\tListado de Numeros Pares\n\n");
    for(f = 0; f < i; f++){
        printf("numero1[%d] = %d\n",f+1,numero1[f]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("\tListado de Numeros Impares\n\n");
    for(f = 0; f < j; f++){
        printf("numero2[%d] = %d\n",f+1,numero2[f]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida Accimus, se agradece que te hayas tomado la molestia en ayudar a OP con tu respuesta.  ¿Podrías añadir en tu respuesta alguna indicación de qué hace tu código? De esa manera no solo ayudarías a OP, sino al resto de personas que encuentre esta pregunta en el futuro.